# An error on Ripley's K function on spatstat

Tags: r, plot, spatial, spatstat

I would like some help with the Kest function on spatstat. I'm trying to calculate de Ripley's K for my simulate data. When I try to run the function the R show me some error, that says:

> Error: 7 segments do not lie entirely inside the window.

But when I plot the map, all the points shows perfectly inside the observation window.
I am using the following codes:

```
library(spatstat)
library(sp)
library(maptools)

pemt.area <- readShapePoly("Fragment/Fragment_SIRGAS.shp")
pemt.area <- as(pemt.area, "owin")
plot(pemt.area)

tree.simu <- read.table("simulation.txt", h=T)
tree.simu
tree.simu.ppp<- ppp(x=tree.simu$X,y=tree.simu$Y,window=pemt.area)
plot(tree.simu.ppp)

ripley <- Kest(tree.simu.ppp, correction="isotropic", domain=pemt.area, var.approx=TRUE, ratio=TRUE)
plot(ripley, main = "K function")
```

I tryed to look up on the vignette but I had no success on fixing this problem.

The following link contains the data files. If you need something else, please let me know: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B_cWshGkkAzjbHBnemNuMzh1Q1k&usp=sharing

Thank you, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Just like in the answer by @carl-witthoft I can run all the code without errors. Could you please provide info about operating system and versions of R and spatstat? 
PS: Please remember to accept answers if they solved your problem (sorry, I had somehow missed that this answer was accepted, but the remark still replies to a previous question of yours that I tried to answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not related to `Kest` or `ppp`.

Notice that the error message is talking about **segments**, not **points**.

This is an error message from the `spatstat` function `psp` which creates a spatial pattern of line segments. The error indicates that the polygon data are not conforming to the requirements. It is most likely to be happening during the call to `readShapePoly` or `as.owin`. To track it down, you could type `traceback()` immediately after the error report, and this will show where the error is occurring.

First it would be wise to update all your packages.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce your problem.  Here is the K graph I generated.[image: Kfunc.jpg]

In my case: OSX, R 3.1.0 .   All I can suggest is to make sure your packages are up to date and to double-check that the files you're using are identical to the ones in your link.

Comment: I believe earlier versions of spatstat would fail to make the point pattern if any points were outside of the window - whereas now it just gives a warning and the number of points outside. A potential quick fix is to dilate the window, e.g. `BiggerWindow <- dilation(pemt.area, 100)` if the area is in meters would make a 100 meter buffer. But note this will change edge corrections and density estimates - so use with caution.